# How can I run an hdparm command after boot and resume on Fedora 19?

Tags: fedora, hard-disk, power-management

I bought a new HD(WD5000BPVT) which unfortunately tries to sleep every 5-8 seconds. Not only is the clicking noise quite audible, the 1-second spinup time adds very noticeable latency in day-to-day use.

I've found `hdparm -B 254 /dev/sda` will disable the very short sleep but I don't know how to enforce this setting every time the drive is powered on. The `dconf-editor` and 'Power Management Preferences' apps both do nothing with regard to HD settings. I don't have any `/etc/hdparm` or `/etc/acpi` paths. MATE is the window manager.

On Fedora 19, how can I force this command to run whenever the drive is activated?

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem none of the solutions here suited my needs. Using cron is really a workaround, not a solution, udev rules are run when power is connected/disconnected but not after suspending/resuming and `pm-utils` are no longer used by default in Fedora 19 when you for example close lid of your laptop.

Since `systemd` is now responsible for suspending/hibernating, I think that the only proper way to handle this situation is to create a `systemd` unit that will run both after boot and after resuming from suspend.

Notes:

- By using `/dev/disk/by-id/...` instead of `/dev/sda`, you are always be sure to get the right disk (sda,b,c depends on the order they are detected by the kernel)
- You can have multiple `ExecStart` lines so you can configure multiple disks

Here's the unit I wrote:

```
[Unit]
Description=Silence HD
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
# Disable automatic head parking for the main disk
ExecStart=/sbin/hdparm -B 254 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3250824AS_4N127FD1
# Enable automatic spin down after 30 seconds for the second, infrequently used disk
ExecStart=/sbin/hdparm -S 6 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST31000528AS_BVP5H5X1

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target basic.target
```

Save this file as `/etc/systemd/system/hdsilence.service` and then enable it using:

```
systemctl enable hdsilence.service
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: Works great here on Fedora 20, too. Thank you!

Comment: So this makes changes to /etc/hdparm.conf obsolete?

Comment: @domih: As far as I can tell the hdparm.conf is a Debian thing and it is not supported on Fedora.

Answer (score 7):

You can have the system run the command during boot by creating your own systemd service or adding the command to /etc/rc.d/rc.local.

If you want the command to run every time you *wake* the system after sleep/hibernate, you can add a script that starts with 2 digits to /etc/pm/sleep.d/, look at the other scripts in /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d (assuming x86_64) for more details.  Basically, it takes a parameter depending on which state it is entering.  You might also need to add some login to power.d/ in the same parent directory if you want to operate differently on battery power compared to when plugged in.

Comment: `creating your own systemd service` can you be more specific? I don't have a /etc/rc.d/rc.local file.

Comment: The [systemd documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) explains the syntax of a systemd service unit.  The `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` file is just a shell script, create it and make sure its executable.

Answer (score 3):

For different settings when running on AC / battery, I'd do it via a simple `udev` rule, e.g.
`/etc/udev/rules.d/98-apmsettings.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE}=="0", RUN+="/usr/bin/hdparm -B 128 /dev/sda"
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE}=="1", RUN+="/usr/bin/hdparm -B 254 /dev/sda"
```

This would set `apm` to `254` when the laptop is plugged in and respectively `128` when unplugged. Also, it should always work, even after resuming from suspend.

Comment: For those who like copying verbatim, newer releases have `hdparm` in `/usr/sbin`, so adjust the paths.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same disk (and the same problem). My stupid but working solution: I have put that in `/etc/crontab`:

```
-*/5  * * * *   root  hdparm -B 254 /dev/sda
```

Comment: Doesn't this simply access the drive every 12 seconds? I considered something along that line but I kinda would like some level of sleep when undocked.

Comment: Every five minutes. You may write a wrapper script which checks the power state of the system.

Answer (score 1):

The udev rules work well on plug events, but to get the correct behaviour after resume from suspend I need somthing like this in `/etc/pm/sleep.d`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
    if grep -q 1 /sys/class/power_supply/ADP1/online; then
      /usr/sbin/hdparm -B 254 /dev/sda
    else
      /usr/sbin/hdparm -B 128 /dev/sda
    fi
;;
esac
```