# To configure hard drive APM levels and maintain them after suspend/resume

Tags: fedora, systemd, hard-disk, power-management, hdparm

On Fedora 25, my laptop's hard drive has a very low APM level (power management), so I use the udev rules from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80487/218050) to adjust it with `hdparm`. However, after resuming from suspend, the APM level gets reset. Manually triggering the udev rules from the terminal works, so to automate it I tried using the following systemd service adapted from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99120/trigger-udev-rules-from-systemd) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89013/218050):-

```
[Unit]
Description=Re-run udev power_supply rules after resuming from suspend
After=supend.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=+/bin/sh -c '/usr/sbin/udevadm trigger --subsystem-match="power_supply"'

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

I also tried combinations of `multi-user.target`, `default.target` and `sleep.target` in the `WantedBy=` line, as well as `Type=simple`. None of this worked, so I tried placing a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`, adapted from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177937/218050). But this did not work either (nor did putting it in `/usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/`).

Finally, the man page for `systemd-suspend.service` says,

> ... scripts or binaries dropped in `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` are intended for local use ... and should be considered hacks. If applications want to be notified of system suspend/hibernation and resume, there are much nicer interfaces available.

However, placing a script in `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` actually works; but in any case, what are these "much nicer interfaces" and how do I use them to either run the udev trigger (preferable) or `hdparm` after resuming from suspend? Better still, is there a way to set the hard drive APM levels for on-battery and plugged-in states by means of some static configuration instead of udev rules?

**Update - Fixed**
The systemd service is working now. I think I mistakenly used `udevadm` from the wrong directory while trying various combinations. I have posted [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/347731/218050) clarifying this. I apologise for any confusion caused. However, there is still the question of whether there is a way to do this statically (without udev rules).

Comment: `User=root Group=root` should not be required. Note that you are not an application. IMO the scripts are a nice method for local use, except that being in `/usr` confuses me. Also there's an "application" that will handle this, although the version in F25 doesn't. Ticket: https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/issues/72 Code: https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/pull/73 It listens for suspend events using a D-Bus interface that "logind" provides... don't ask me to justify that :).

Comment: I had put in the `root` parts after I found that it didn't work; I think they do no harm anyway. Also, I had already gone through that storaged thread. It still seems to be a problem, and the problem seems to be more or less the same - APM level reset after resuming from suspend. Lastly, on Fedora (25) `/lib` is a link to `/usr/lib`, which is why the scripts are there; don't know if you meant something else.

Comment: If the storaged commit doesn't work, please file a bug - but the commit is dated 21st July, and storaged 2.6.2 is dated 16th June, so I don't believe the commit is in F25.

Comment: The issue was reopened on 21st July, and the copr seems to be for F26. Still, I'll see if it works and follow your advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I had initially used `udevadm` from the wrong directory (`/bin/udevadm`), and then got one or other combination wrong while trying things out. *The `udevadm` program must be run from `/sbin` (or `/usr/sbin`).* The following systemd service now suffices:-

```
[Unit]
Description=Re-run udev power_supply rules after resuming from suspend
After=supend.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=power_supply

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

I apologise for any confusion caused.

Answer (score 1):

[Writing a systemd service to be executed at resume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124212/writing-a-systemd-service-to-be-executed-at-resume#comment491330_227293)

> Works with **After=suspend.target in Unit** and WantedBy=multi-user.target sleep.target in Install.

In your case the second part would be `WantedBy=sleep.target`.

Apparently `After=sleep.target` worked for one person, but another had to use `After=suspend.target`.  I have no idea why.  The interface for using this to run units on *resume* does not seem to be documented, so I wouldn't really claim that it is nicer.

Comment: I had seen that line and tried it, to no avail. The `sleep.target` doesn't work either in `After=` or in `WantedBy=`.

Comment: I think we're being a bit unclear - just to be sure: for the unit to work properly it would need to include some line for both `WantedBy=` and `After=`. Anyway, are you seeing your unit being started if you look in `sudo journalctl -b`, is it that it starts at the wrong time, or is it that it doesn't start? You can press End, then search backwards in the pager by typing `?`, and entering a search string, such as `Re-run udev power_supply`, `Start`, or `systemd`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I did set both `After=` and `WantedBy=` but no matter which combination of `suspend.target` and `sleep.target` I used for them, it didn't work. However, my original service (with just `suspend.target` in both `After=` and `WantedBy=`) is working now. I think it was my own mistake; I've put the reason in [an answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/347731/218050). The service unit status shows up correctly in both `systemctl status` and `journalctl`.